# VBA to restrict input in sheet2 column A to the same values found in sheet1 columnA

Tags: vba, excel

Anyway I can restrict any values in sheet2 column A to whatever values were found in sheet1 columnA? If the user puts in a value in sheet2 column A that is not found in sheet1 columnA, a msgbox will come up and restrict the input.  Perhaps use VBA for this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in sheet2 module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 1 Then
    LastRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    With Sheet1.Range("a1:a" & LastRow)
        Set c = .Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Beep
    MsgBox Target & " is not found in Sheet1 Column A"
    Target = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great! Would you happen to know how to select every other row in the sheet1 column A? Because in column A (sheet1) I have input, then new row is comment and then input then comment again.

Comment: Oh John, I notice it takes about 15 secs for sheet2 to search for the item in sheet1. Do you know if there's a way to speed it up? The last row the code needs to search is the last one with something inputed.

Comment: The .find method is the fastest search method I know.  How many used rows do you have in Sheet1.  It would take many, many rows to make it take 15 seconds per search.  Something else might be slowing it down.  But no, I don't know how to make the .find method search only every other row.  Maybe you should try putting all the dat in sheet1.column"A" into an array - and search through the array.  That is the only thing that would be faster than the .find method.  Let me take a look.  Is your data on odd rows and comments on even rows?

Comment: I just tested it with 11,000 pieces of data in column A and it found a word in row 10,033 in less than a second.  Now the "LastRow" variable above is set to get the last used row of the entire sheet1, not just column "A".  Try changing that to "LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row"

Comment: also change the following line "Set c = .Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues)" to this: "Set c = .Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues LookAt:=xlWhole)"

Comment: I took your suggestion to make a new list in another worksheet that takes in only the rows I want and it made the search super fast. It might just be that my laptop is super slow and it's just really laggy. You're such a lifesaver, this works so well!! THANKSS <3 :)

Comment: Good!  Glad to help